# No route matches [GET] "/posts/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am completely new to ruby, andI am following [this ruby rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) step by step, except for the detail that I've called my app "cinema".

I created a resource named "posts", there is a controller class called posts controller. From the page posts/new I should post a text with title, and execute an action (show). I am trying to add the show action in the routes file and in the controller class.

The show action should be called when a form is submitted, the form includes a title and a text field, mapped into the database.

In [paragraph 5.7](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-posts), there is a non-clear instruction: it says to add this line:

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
```

To my `routes.rb` file, but it doesn't say where to write it exactly, I put it under `resources:posts` (maybe it's the wrong place, it doesn't saying anything about that).

I also added the show method to the controller class:

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title,:test);
    end
```

But when I submit the form I still get this error:

[image]

The `rake routes` command result:

> Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
>   welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)  welcome#index
>           root GET    /                         welcome#index
>          posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
>                POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
>       new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
>      edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
>           post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
>                PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
>                PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
>                DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy

Comment: Try restarting your rails server

Comment: Can you please show us your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: show us your routes by running: `rake routes`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't tell you to add it to `routes.rb`. It's one of the routes that is created automatically with:

```
resources :posts
```

Remove the line from your `routes.rb` restart the server and continue with the tutorial.

Tip: you can run `rake routes` to see all available routes in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole question seems completely contradictory to me.

- You never do this in rails routes - 
  `post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show`

  Instead in routes.rb file.
  `get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show'`
- The routing is done on a priority basis (first come first serve), so if your are adding get 'posts/:id' after the resources :posts, it is of no use as resources :posts already does it for you (read the rails routing guide on resources).
- Your form submission should be a post data, if you are using resources 'new' should be a 'get' data and the corresponding 'post' should be 'create'. Your 'new' route has an error, then where else are you rendering your form to submit the form data?

My suggestion is that you keep the 'resources :post' and remove every other this corresponding to your :post from routes file. If you have everything else right then it should probably work fine.

Answer (score -1):

1. resources :posts
   delete it
2. rails s
3. paste resources :posts
4. rails s
   I make it and success

Comment: What is this supposed to do?